# How to add selected file name in label with remove option using input type=“file” and ngFor in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular, I'm trying to display list of labels with remove button, when selecting file from folder using **input type=“file”** using below code,

```
 <input #fileInput type="file"  />
<button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>
```

And I want to remove the added file name from that list by clicking remove button in that corresponding row using **ngFor** option. Can anyone suggest me an idea to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In ts file**

```
    files = [];

    onFileChange(event) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
            this.files.push(this.selectedFile);
        }
    }

    removeFile(index) {
           this.files.splice(i, 1);
    }
```

**In html file**

```
    <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)"/> 
    <button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>

    <div *ngFor="let file of files;let i = index;">
      {{file.name}} <span (click)="removeFile(i)"> Remove</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the corresponding element in your remove function and remove value of that input field, like below -

```
<div *ngFor='let item of list; let i = index'>
  <input #fileInput type="file"  />
  <button type="button" (click)="fileInput.click()">trigger</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="reset(fileInput, i)">Reset</button>
</div>


reset(element, index) {
    console.log(element);
    element.value = "";
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-reset?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: sorry its not working. I have placed input field and trigger button outside the div tag. Its replacing the current file and its not listing the selected file.